# Why can't I get my RoR app to look at the compiled files in prod?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have developed a RoR-application that runs perfectly fine in dev-environment but as soon as I upload it to Heroku it breaks. This is because my assets (Stimulus JS-controllers) are not being loaded. I have been trying to find out what is wrong and it seems to come down to the fact that my app is trying to serve my non-compiled files. I have attempted the heroku-way using `config.serve_static_files = true` but to no gain. I am all lost for clues at this point... Using Rails 7.

[image: The error messages in console, in prod]

[image: Location of the compiled files]

Tried to clear assets, re-compile, change paths but it does not make sense as I am expecting Rails self to try to load those pre-compiled assets with a hash on them.
This is what I see in Heroku-logs: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/controllers/openinghours_controller.js"):`

Comment: I first made a comment (that I have deleted ) saying I suspected your app to not run in production mode at Heroku. I suggested to check your environment variable, and the deployment logs to verify Puma (or another webserver you are using) is indeed booting in "production". Though I realise it is unlikely. What is strange is that your stimulus controllers are pinged directly. Usually they are bundled into "application.js" and application.js is added through a helper. I am wondering why your app tries to ping them independently.. Can you tell us how you bundle stimulus ?

Comment: Yeah, fair questions though, but it is indeed running in production and logs are 404'ing just like console is. What do you mean by how it is bundled? I am running rake assets:precompile which puts some hashed compiled corresponding files in public/assets, are there any more details I am missing there?

Comment: You may "rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production" instead. Also what I mean is how you append your stimulus controllers to the views? `javascript_pack_tag` ?

Comment: Will try that, and I import it by doing: ```<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>```

Comment: Looks like the solution was to change index.js to
```import { application } from "controllers/application"

// Eager load all controllers defined in the import map under controllers/**/*_controller
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)``` and clearing the precompiled files on Heroku